# Unable to use plotOutput with shinyMobile app in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a R shiny app for a mobile device using the shinyMobile package in R.

UI elements are rendered as expected, but any outputs resulting from the server functions are not rendered.
It seems that e.g. renderPlot or renderTable functions in the server function are never called when the app is running.

In fact, I get the same behavior if I try to run an online example for shiny Mobile. What am I missing here?

If I try to run the code below (from: https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyMobile/man/f7TabLayout.html) the ui is shown, but I would expect to see e.g. the "distPlot1" and "distPlot2" plot, but these are not rendered.

> 

```
library(shinyMobile)

if(interactive()){
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyMobile)
 library(shinyWidgets)

 shinyApp(
   ui = f7Page(
     title = "Tab layout",
     f7TabLayout(
       tags$head(
         tags$script(
           "$(function(){
               $('#tapHold').on('taphold', function () {
                 app.dialog.alert('Tap hold fired!');
               });
             });
             "
         )
       ),
       panels = tagList(
         f7Panel(title = "Left Panel", side = "left", theme = "light", "Blabla", effect = "cover"),
         f7Panel(title = "Right Panel", side = "right", theme = "dark", "Blabla", effect = "cover")
       ),
       navbar = f7Navbar(
         title = "Tabs",
         hairline = FALSE,
         shadow = TRUE,
         leftPanel = TRUE,
         rightPanel = TRUE
       ),
       f7Tabs(
         animated = FALSE,
         swipeable = TRUE,
         f7Tab(
           tabName = "Tab 1",
           icon = f7Icon("envelope"),
           active = TRUE,
           f7Shadow(
             intensity = 10,
             hover = TRUE,
             f7Card(
               title = "Card header",
               f7Stepper(
                 "obs1",
                 "Number of observations",
                 min = 0,
                 max = 1000,
                 value = 500,
                 step = 100
               ),
               plotOutput("distPlot1"),
               footer = tagList(
                 f7Button(inputId = "tapHold", label = "My button"),
                 f7Badge("Badge", color = "green")
               )
             )
           )
         ),
         f7Tab(
           tabName = "Tab 2",
           icon = f7Icon("today"),
           active = FALSE,
           f7Shadow(
             intensity = 10,
             hover = TRUE,
             f7Card(
               title = "Card header",
               f7Select(
                 inputId = "obs2",
                 label = "Distribution type:",
                 choices = c(
                   "Normal" = "norm",
                   "Uniform" = "unif",
                   "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                   "Exponential" = "exp"
                 )
               ),
               plotOutput("distPlot2"),
               footer = tagList(
                 f7Button(label = "My button", href = "https://www.google.com"),
                 f7Badge("Badge", color = "orange")
               )
             )
           )
         ),
         f7Tab(
           tabName = "Tab 3",
           icon = f7Icon("cloud_upload"),
           active = FALSE,
           f7Shadow(
             intensity = 10,
             hover = TRUE,
             f7Card(
               title = "Card header",
               f7SmartSelect(
                 inputId = "variable",
                 label = "Variables to show:",
                 c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                   "Transmission" = "am",
                   "Gears" = "gear"),
                 multiple = TRUE,
                 selected = "cyl"
               ),
               tableOutput("data"),
               footer = tagList(
                 f7Button(label = "My button", href = "https://www.google.com"),
                 f7Badge("Badge", color = "green")
               )
             )
           )
         )
       )
     )
   ),
   server = function(input, output) {
     output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
       dist <- rnorm(input$obs1)
       hist(dist)
     })

     output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
       dist <- switch(
         input$obs2,
         norm = rnorm,
         unif = runif,
         lnorm = rlnorm,
         exp = rexp,
         rnorm
       )

       hist(dist(500))
     })

     output$data <- renderTable({
       mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
     }, rownames = TRUE)
   }
 )
}
```

Comment: Not reproducible: I see histograms on Tabs 1 and 2 (Tab 1 reacts when I change the number of observations) and a listing of mpg and cyl from mtcars on Tab 3.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately I don't get this behavior, no histograms etc. So this must be something in my (R) environment, but I am unable to find the cause. Did anyone deal with this before? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@RDW uninstall the shinyMobile package, then type this into your console

```
devtools::install_github("RinteRface/shinyMobile@rc-1.0.0")
```

For more info on solving the challenge check this issue on the author's [GitHub](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinyMobile/issues/228).
I had the same issue but on performing the above I was able to resolve it.